# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'. I am getting this error when adding a new layer to a model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

```
ml = Sequential()
ml.add(LSTM(64,dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5,return_sequences=True))
```

This is giving me a error: `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'`.

`ml` is the name of the model. I am unable to add any layers to a model. Please help.

The dependencies that I am using are:

- Tensorflow: 2.0.0-beta1
- Keras: 2.2.4
- Python: 3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to latest `Tensorflow` version instead of Beta Version.And use the import functions as mentioned below.

**To install:**

```
pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
#OR
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

**Importing:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM

ml = Sequential()
ml.add(LSTM(64,dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5,return_sequences=True))
```

Your code should work fine now.